# Genetic Algorithm in R: Specify number of 1s in binary chromosomes

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm, rbga

I am using the [rbga](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/genalg/html/rbga.bin.html) function, but my question still stands for other genetic algorithm implementations in R. Is there a way to specify the number of 1s in binary chromosomes?

I have the following example provided by the library documentation.

```
data(iris)
library(MASS)
X <- as.data.frame(cbind(scale(iris[,1:4]), matrix(rnorm(36*150), 150, 36)))
Y <- iris[,5]

iris.evaluate <- function(indices) {
    print("Chromosome")
    print(indices)
    print("================================")
    result = 1
    if (sum(indices) > 2) {
        huhn <- lda(X[,indices==1], Y, CV=TRUE)$posterior
        result = sum(Y != dimnames(huhn)[[2]][apply(huhn, 1,
                                                    function(x)
                                                        which(x == max(x)))]) / length(Y)
    }
    result
}

monitor <- function(obj) {
    minEval = min(obj$evaluations);
    plot(obj, type="hist");
}

woppa <- rbga.bin(size=40, mutationChance=0.05, zeroToOneRatio=10,
                  evalFunc=iris.evaluate, showSettings=TRUE, verbose=TRUE)
```

Here are some of the chromosomes.

```
"Chromosome"
 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
"================================"
"Chromosome"
 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
"================================"
"Chromosome"
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
"================================"
"Chromosome"
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
"================================"
```

The 1s (i.e., the chosen characteristics) are 5, 8, 5 and 4 respectively.

I am trying to follow the technique specified in a [paper](https://users.elis.ugent.be/%7Eleeckhou/papers/micro07-hot-tutorial.pdf) and they claim that they apply a genetic algorithm and in the end they pick a specific number of characteristics.

1. Is it possible to specify in a genetic algorithm the number of characteristics that I want my solution(s)/chromosome(s) to have?
2. Could this be done on the final solution/chromosome and if yes how?

Comment: Have a fitness function that rewards chromosomes that have  the target number of characteristics and penalizes those which depart from it? Your question might be easier to answer if you provided a link to the paper that you are trying to follow.

Comment: I have included the paper link. In the beginning of Page 68 (Page 6 of the PDF), they mention: "The GA’s end result is a limited number of program characteristics that accurately characterize a program’s behavior. In selecting eight program characteristics (to yield the same dimensionality that we obtained with PCA), the GA achieved a 0.86 correlation coefficient between the distances in the original data set compared with the distances in the reduced data set." I'm not sure how they can specifically select 8 characteristics. Shouldn't the number of them be determined by the best solution?

Comment: Also, they specify the steps of the fitness score evaluation. There isn't anything there about rewarding/penalizing a specific number of characteristics.